# Comparison of GradientDescent algorithm in tensorflow with the implementation of Michael Nielsen

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

First I will give an overview of my problem. I have two setups:

1) A net which is based on tensorflow

2) A net which is based on code from Michael Nielsen's Book http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html

Both nets are completely equal. They both have

- 3 hidden layers a 30 neurons
- 2 inputs neurons, one output neuron
- All activations are sigmoid
- Stochastic Gradient descent algorithm as learning algorithm with eta=3.0
- quadratic cost function : cost_function = tf.scalar_mul(1.0/(N_training_set*2.0),tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(y,y_)))
- batch_size of 10
- weight initialization: The weights which connect the lth and l+1th layer are initialized with sigma=1/sqrt(N_l), where N_l is the number of neurons in the lth layer.

My problem is, that the tensorflow results are very bad ( a factor 10 worse than the results one obtains if I use the Nielsen code).
So before I post my complete code: Does anybody know that there is a bug in the tensorflow StochasticGradientDescent algorithm? (Or does anybody has a reference how the learning rate of the Stocharstic Gradient Descent in tensorflow is defined? I cannot find something in the api)

Here is my code for the tensorflow net:
regression.py

```py
import readData
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from random import randint
import random
from root_numpy import fill_hist

from ROOT import TCanvas, TH2F, TText, TF1 ,TH1D
import ROOT

import tensorflow as tf

import math



# # # # # # ##
#Read in data#
#            #

function_outputs=True# apply an invertable function to the y's and train with the modified outputs y_mod! Up to know this function is just a normalization.
function_inputs=True # 


full_set =  readData.read_data_set("./TH2D_A00_TB10.root","LHCChi2_CMSSM_nObs1061_A00_TB10","full_set",function_inputs,function_outputs)

N_full_set=full_set.get_N()
N_validation_set=10000
N_training_set=N_full_set-(N_validation_set)

full=range(0,N_full_set)

random.shuffle(full)
training_subset=full[:N_training_set]#indices for training set
validation_subset=full[N_training_set:N_training_set+N_validation_set]#indices for validation set



training_set = readData.read_data_set("./TH2D_A00_TB10.root","LHCChi2_CMSSM_nObs1061_A00_TB10","training_set",
                                      function_inputs,function_outputs,full_set=full_set,subset=training_subset)
validation_set = readData.read_data_set("./TH2D_A00_TB10.root","LHCChi2_CMSSM_nObs1061_A00_TB10","validation_set",
                                   function_inputs,function_outputs,full_set=full_set,subset=validation_subset )

#overwiew of full data set, training_data set and validation_data set. The modified members( normalized in this case) can be accessed with the x_mod() and y_mod() member functions
#the normalized data (input and output) will be used to train the net
print "full_data_set:"
print "x (inputs)"
print full_set.get_x()
print "y (outputs)"
print full_set.get_y()
print "x_mod"
print full_set.get_x_mod()
print "y_mod"
print full_set.get_y_mod()
print "------------------"
print "training_data_set:"
print "x (inputs)"
print training_set.get_x()
print "y (outputs)"
print training_set.get_y()
print "x_mod"
print training_set.get_x_mod()
print "y_mod"
print training_set.get_y_mod()
print "------------------"
print "evaluation_data_set:"
print "x (inputs)"
print validation_set.get_x()
print "y (outputs)"
print validation_set.get_y()
print "x_mod"
print validation_set.get_x_mod()
print "y_mod"
print validation_set.get_y_mod()
print "------------------"





# # # # # # # # # # # ## 
#setting up the network#
#                      #

N_epochs = 20

learning_rate = 3.0 
batch_size = 10


N1 = 2 #equals N_inputs
N2 = 30
N3 = 30
N4 = 30
N5 = 1

N_in=N1
N_out=N5


#one calculates everything directly for all elements in one batch
"""example: N_in=2,N_out=3, mini_batch_size=5, activation function=linear. In der output matrix gibt es 5Zeilen,jede fuer ein mini batch. Jede Zeile hat 3 Spalten fuer ein output neuron jeweils

W2
[[-0.31917086 -0.03908769  0.5792625 ]
 [ 1.34563279  0.03904691  0.39674851]]
b2
[ 0.40960133 -0.5495823  -0.97048181]
x_in
[[  23.2       12.2    ]
 [   0.         1.1    ]
 [   2.3        3.3    ]
 [  23.22222   24.44444]
 [ 333.       444.     ]]
y=x_in*W2+b2
[[   9.42155647   -0.98004436   17.30874062]
 [   1.88979745   -0.50663072   -0.53405845]
 [   4.1160965    -0.51062918    1.67109203]
 [  25.8909874    -0.50280523   22.17957497]
 [ 491.5866394     3.77104688  368.08026123]]

hier wird klar, dass b2 auf jede Zeile der Matrix x_in*w2 draufaddiert wird.
W2 ist die transponierte der atrix, die im Buch definiert ist.
"""

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,N1])#don't take the shape=(batch_size,N1) argument, because we need this for different batch sizes


W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N1, N2],mean=0.0,stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(N1*1.0)))# Initialize the weights for one neuron with 1/sqrt(Number of weights which enter the neuron/ Number of neurons in layer before)
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N2]))
a2 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W2) + b2) #x=a1

W3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N2, N3],mean=0.0,stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(N2*1.0)))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N3]))
a3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(a2, W3) + b3)

W4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N3, N4],mean=0.0,stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(N3*1.0)))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N4]))
a4 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(a3, W4) + b4)

W5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N4, N5],mean=0.0,stddev=1.0/math.sqrt(N4*1.0)))
b5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N5]))
y = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(a4, W5) + b5)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,N_out]) #  ,shape=(None,N_out)






# # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#initializing and training#
#                         #

cost_function = tf.scalar_mul(1.0/(N_training_set*2.0),tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(y,y_))) 
error_to_desired_output= y-y_
abs_error_to_desired_output= tf.abs(y-y_)
sum_abs_error_to_desired_output= tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y-y_))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost_function) 
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

#launch the graph
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


N_training_batch=training_set.get_N()/batch_size #rounds to samllest integer

out_mod_validation=[0]*N_epochs # output of net, when inputting x_mod of validation data. Will be saved after each epoch.
error_mod_validation_data= [0]*N_epochs #absolute error on mod validation data after each epoch
diff_mod_validation=[0]*N_epochs # error vector of validation data after each epoch. i.e. y-y_

cost_training_data=[0]*N_epochs


for i in range(0,N_epochs):
    for j in range(0,N_training_batch):
        batch_xs, batch_ys, epochs_completed = training_set.next_batch(batch_size)#always gives the modified x's and y's. If one does not want to modifie them the function has to be set to identity 
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, 
            y_: batch_ys})

    cost_training_data[i]=sess.run(cost_function, feed_dict={
        x: training_set.get_x_mod(), y_: training_set.get_y_mod()})
    out_mod_validation[i]= sess.run(y, feed_dict={
        x: validation_set.get_x_mod()})# output of net, when imputting x_mod of validation data after each training epoch
    diff_mod_validation[i]=sess.run(error_to_desired_output, feed_dict={
        x: validation_set.get_x_mod(),y_: validation_set.get_y_mod()})
    error_mod_validation_data[i]=sess.run(sum_abs_error_to_desired_output, feed_dict={
        x: validation_set.get_x_mod(),y_: validation_set.get_y_mod()})
    print "epochs completed: "+str(i)

#now calculate everything for the unmodified/unnormalized outputs
out_validation=[0]*N_epochs # output of net, when inputting x_mod of validation data and making the normalization of the output backwards, saved after each epoch
error_validation_data=[0.0]*N_epochs
diff_validation=[0.0]*N_epochs

#make the transformation on the outputs backwards
for i in range(0,N_epochs):
  out_validation[i]=np.ndarray(shape=(validation_set.get_N(),1))
  for j in range(0,len(out_mod_validation[i])):
    out_validation[i][j]=out_mod_validation[i][j]#do this, because otherwise we will produce only a reference

  readData.apply_inverse_function_to_outputs(out_mod_validation[i],out_validation[i],full_set.get_y_max())# second argument will be changed!

  diff_validation[i]=np.subtract(out_validation[i],validation_set.get_y())
  error_validation_data[i]=np.sum(np.absolute(np.subtract(out_validation[i],validation_set.get_y())))

#print at 10 examples how good the output matches the desired output
for i in range(0,10):
    print "desired output"
    print validation_set.get_y()[i][0]
    print "actual output after last training epoch"
    print out_validation[-1][i][0]
    print "-------"


print "total error on validation_data set after last training"
print error_validation_data[-1]

# # # # ## 
#printing#
#        #


plt.figure(1)
plt.title("Costfunction of (modified) Training-data")
plt.xlabel("epochs")
plt.ylabel("cost function")
x_range=[x+1 for x in range(0,N_epochs)]
plt.plot(x_range,cost_training_data)
plt.savefig("cost_on_training_data.png")

plt.figure(2)
plt.title("f data")
plt.xlabel("epochs")
plt.ylabel("total error on validation data")
x_range=[x+1 for x in range(0,N_epochs)]
plt.plot(x_range,error_validation_data)
plt.savefig("error_on_val_data.png")




error_on_validation_data_after_training = diff_validation[-1].reshape((1,validation_set.get_N()))           
hist=TH1D('hist',"Errors on val data after last training epoch",200,-10000,10000)
fill_hist(hist,error_on_validation_data_after_training[0])
canvas=TCanvas(); 
hist.GetXaxis().SetTitle("desired Chi^2- outputted Chi^2");
hist.Draw()
canvas.SaveAs('error_on_val_data_hist.png')
```

readData.py

```html
import numpy as np
import root_numpy
from ROOT import TFile, TH2D, TCanvas
import itertools


def apply_function_to_inputs(x,x_mod,x_max):# python uebergibt alles als reference
   #normalize the inputs
   for i in range(0,len(x)):
      for j in range(0,len(x[i])):
        #print "x["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]="+str(x[i][j])
        x_mod[i][j]=x[i][j]/x_max[j]
        #print "x_mod["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]="+str(x_mod[i][j])

def apply_inverse_function_to_inputs(x,x_mod,x_max):# python uebergibt alles als reference
   #re normalize the inputs
   for i in range(0,len(x)):
      for j in range(0,len(x[i])):
        x_mod[i][j]=x[i][j]*x_max[j]

def apply_function_to_outputs(y,y_mod,y_max):# python uebergibt alles als reference
   #normalize the outputs
   for i in range(0,len(y)):
      for j in range(0,len(y[i])):
        y_mod[i][j]=y[i][j]/y_max[j]

def apply_inverse_function_to_outputs(y,y_mod,y_max):# python uebergibt alles als reference
   #re-normalize the outputs
   for i in range(0,len(y)):
      for j in range(0,len(y[i])):
        y_mod[i][j]=y[i][j]*y_max[j]

class Dataset(object):
  def __init__(self,path,hist_name,kind_of_set,function_inputs,function_outputs,full_set,subset):
    
    self._kind_of_set=kind_of_set     
    
    """example
    self._x np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,2))
    [[   10.    95.]
     [   10.   100.]
     [   10.   105.]
     ..., 
     [ 2490.  1185.]
     [ 2490.  1190.]
     [ 2490.  1195.]]


    self._y np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,1))
    [[  0.00000000e+00]
     [  0.00000000e+00]
     [  0.00000000e+00]
     ..., 
     [  6.34848448e-06]
     [  6.34845946e-06]
     [  6.34848448e-06]]
    """

    rfile = TFile(path)
    histogram = rfile.Get(hist_name)

    #now prepare data for training:
    if kind_of_set=="full_set":
        N_points=histogram.GetXaxis().GetNbins() * histogram.GetYaxis().GetNbins() #number of points in full_set
        self._N=N_points
        self._y=np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,1))
        self._x=np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,2))
        self._y_mod=np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,1)) #function applied to outputs, for example normalized, or a function is applied
        self._x_mod=np.ndarray(shape=(N_points,2)) #function applied to inputs
        self._y_max=np.ndarray(shape=(1))
        self._y_max[0]=0.0
        self._x_max=np.ndarray(shape=(2))
        self._x_max=np.ndarray(shape=(2))
 self._x_max[0]=0.0
 self._x_max[1]=0.0
        i=0
        for x_bin in range(0, histogram.GetXaxis().GetNbins()):
            for y_bin in range(0, histogram.GetYaxis().GetNbins()):
                self._x[i][0]=histogram.GetXaxis().GetBinCenter(x_bin)
                self._x[i][1]=histogram.GetYaxis().GetBinCenter(y_bin)
                self._y[i][0]=histogram.GetBinContent(x_bin,y_bin)
                for j in range(0,len(self._x[i])):# only in the full_set case the maximum values are calculated
                  if self._x[i][j]>self._x_max[j]:
                    self._x_max[j]=self._x[i][j]
                for j in range(0,len(self._y[i])):
                  if self._y[i][j]>self._y_max[j]:
                    self._y_max[j]=self._y[i][j]
                i=i+1
 #apply function to inputs and outputs, the function can also be the identity
 apply_function_to_inputs(self._x,self._x_mod,self._x_max)
 apply_function_to_outputs(self._y,self._y_mod,self._y_max)
      
               
    elif kind_of_set=="training_set" or kind_of_set=="validation_set" or kind_of_set=="test_set":
        self._N = len(subset)#Number of elements of the data set
        self._y=np.ndarray(shape=(self._N,1))
        self._x=np.ndarray(shape=(self._N,2))
        self._y_mod=np.ndarray(shape=(self._N,1))
        self._x_mod=np.ndarray(shape=(self._N,2))
        self._y_max=full_set.get_y_max()
        self._x_max=full_set.get_x_max()
        for i in range(0,self._N):
            self._x[i][0]=full_set.get_x()[subset[i]][0]
            self._x[i][1]=full_set.get_x()[subset[i]][1]
            self._y[i][0]=full_set.get_y()[subset[i]][0]
            self._x_mod[i][0]=full_set.get_x_mod()[subset[i]][0]
            self._x_mod[i][1]=full_set.get_x_mod()[subset[i]][1]
            self._y_mod[i][0]=full_set.get_y_mod()[subset[i]][0]     



    

    if len(self._x)==0:# If the set has 0 entries the list  is empty
      self._N_input=-1
    else:
      self._N_input = len(self._x[0])

    if len(self._y)==0:# If the set has 0 entries the list  is empty
      self._N_output=-1
    else:
      self._N_output = len(self._y[0])

    self._index_in_epoch = 0 #if one has trained 2 mini batches in the epoch already then this is 2*batch_size
    self._epochs_completed = 0


  def get_N_input_nodes(self):
    return self._N_input

  def get_N_output_nodes(self):
    return self._N_output

  def get_N(self):
    return self._N

  def get_x(self):
    return self._x

  def get_y(self):
    return self._y

  def get_x_max(self):
    return self._x_max

  def get_y_max(self):
    return self._y_max

  def get_x_mod(self):
    return self._x_mod
  
  def get_y_mod(self):
    return self._y_mod

  def next_batch(self, batch_size, fake_x=False):
    start = self._index_in_epoch
    self._index_in_epoch += batch_size
    if self._index_in_epoch >= self._N:
      # Finished epoch
      self._epochs_completed += 1
      # Shuffle the data
      perm = np.arange(self._N)
      np.random.shuffle(perm)
      self._x = self._x[perm]#shuffle both, actually one would only need to shuffle x_mod and y_mod, but for consistency we shuffle both!
      self._y = self._y[perm]
      self._x_mod = self._x_mod[perm]
      self._y_mod = self._y_mod[perm]
      # Start next epoch
      start = 0
      self._index_in_epoch = batch_size
      assert batch_size <= self._N #if batch size<= self._N then an exception is thrown!
    end = self._index_in_epoch
    return self._x_mod[start:end], self._y_mod[start:end], self._epochs_completed


def read_data_set(path,hist_name,kind_of_set,function_inputs,function_outputs,full_set=None,subset=None):
  return Dataset(path,hist_name,kind_of_set,function_inputs,function_outputs,full_set,subset)
```

I have uploaded the corresponding data input file to
https://github.com/kanban1992/GradientDescent_Comparison

Comment: A `learning_rate` of 3.0 sounds suspiciously high. Do you get better results with a smaller learning rate?

Comment: If anyone is wondering, `eta` is in fact the greek letter η (and not some acronym)

Comment: Sure there might be better choices for eta, but first I want to get consistent results for both  approaches. And no I do not get similar results when I change the learning rate in tensorflow. I have already tried that

Comment: I want to reinforce what @mrry said:  An initial learning rate we typically use with SGD is closer to 0.001.
The application of the gradient is defined here:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L46
A learning rate of 3.0 is amplifying the gradient substantially, and doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Okay, again, the learning rate 3.0 was just choosen to compare both approaches. In this case tensorflow yields very bad results(the output is something like a mean of all outputs of the training set), but the Nielsen net works. When I now vary the learning rate in the tensorflow case, I will never get to performance of the Nielsen Net. And that's strange and tells me that something is not working.

Comment: For those who want to tensorflow and Michael Nielsen code: I created a github rep: https://github.com/kanban1992/GradientDescent_Comparison